# Trying to do a theta, inside a fraction, inside a matrix. Getting errors

Tags: matrices

Trying to show a Jacobian matrix from r, theta.

```
\begin{center} 
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{dr}{dx} && \frac{dr}{dy} \\
    \frac{d \theta }{dx} && \frac{d \theta }{dy}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{center}
```

Getting error `Missing $ inserted` twice.
This error goes away if I remove the `\theta`'s.

I checked, I haven't used a `$` anywhere else. There isn't a non-closed `$`

Comment: Replace begin center and end center with begin equation and end equation, using the same syntax (curly brackets)

Comment: You can't have `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside a math environment.

Comment: As a side note, a Jacobian consists of partial derivatives, so it would be better to replace all `d` for `\partial` ;)

Comment: Which document class do you use, which packages for mathematics have you loaded with which options? Best would be to create a MWE, a minimal working example ...  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @AlanMunn Actually, mods cannot merge accounts anymore, one has to do as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

`bmatrix` can be only in math environment, for example in `\[ ... \]` and not a in a text as you show in your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
\[% <--- replace your \begin{center}
J =
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{dr}{dx}      & \frac{dr}{dy}\\[1ex]
    \frac{d\theta}{dx} & \frac{d\theta}{dy}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\]% <--- replace your \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Above MWE gives:

[image]

**Edit:** I improve the Jacobian: erase superfluous ampersands in matrix as well enlarge distance between matrix's rows.

Comment: I'd remove one of the ampersands on each line.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., good observation, I overlook that there is  superfluous `&`. I will remove them. Thank you to point me on them.